# What's the difference between PCI-e size and bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, pci-express, version, form-factor

There is a note that says :

> 1x PCI-e x16 slot, running at x4

`1x` : the number of slots.
`x16` : the slot size.
`x4` : ???

I know there are 4 sizes (x1, x4, x8, x16)
But also the same numbers for "running at ... "
I know this is not the gen because there is "running at x16"

**What's that x4?**

Comment: Have you read the PCIe Wikipedia article?

Comment: Wikipedia literally has his use case as an example: " An example is a ×16 slot that runs at ×4, which accepts any ×1, ×2, ×4, ×8 or ×16 card, but provides only four lanes."

Comment: I was reading the Wikipedia article but the case I quoted was from a screenshot in a video. Ok now I understand the mechanical vs electrical equation. But *why*? I saw what Wikipedia said but isn't it backward compatible anyways? A x16 card can fit in x4 slot and vice versa. Why make an "empty" larger size slot with no purpose?

Comment: It doesn't have "no purpose", it means you can fit *any* size card in that slot and have them use as many lanes as are available - the x4.

Comment: More questions and answers can be found at https://superuser.com/search?q=x16+x4

Comment: The likely disconnect you are having is in assuming that motherboards have an infinite number of PCIe lanes. They don't. CPUs typically have 16 lanes which by convention on "normal" systems are connected to the primary slot for the graphics card. The rest of the lanes (usually 20-24) come from the system PCH and are shared between NVMe drives, network cards, wifi cards, PCIe-SATA bridges, USB devices and so on. What's left "spare" might be routed to a PCIe slot for the user, but an x16 slot is far more useful to people than an x4 slot which limits what you can physically fit.